# Domain with www pointing to another site

Tags: domain

Recently I started Multi Sites on my VPS, which is running Centos 64 bit. Currently I have two sites live and each is working fine.

Now the problem is in the URL. I have the following sites:

```
http://mbas.co.in
http://u-k.in
```

mbas was the very first site on my VPS

Now both `http://mbas.co.in` and `http://www.mbas.co.in` redirect to my mbas website. However, while `http://u-k.in` redirects correctly to the u-k website, `http://www.u-k.in` redirects me to the mbas website.

You can test this.

My DNS configuration:

[image: Screenshot of DNS settings]

And my Multi Site code is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.mbas.co.in
    ServerName mbas.co.in
    ErrorLog logs/mbas.co.in-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mbas.co.in-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/u-k.in
    ServerName u-k.in
    ErrorLog logs/u-k-error_log
    CustomLog logs/u-k-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ServerAlias(The ServerAlias directive sets the alternate names for a host, for use with name-based virtual hosts):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/u-k.in
    ServerName u-k.in
    ServerAlias www.u-k.in
    ErrorLog logs/u-k-error_log
    CustomLog logs/u-k-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

then reload apache2.

Comment: hey thanks mate, such an easy one I couldn't find, really thanks

Comment: @ntechi if the answer is correct, then confirmed it

Comment: yes I was doing it, but it was popping out, you can mark this answer after 5 mins